# Attach Signed Documents in to Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am suing Docusign Tool Kit to send the Documents for getting the esignature from Salesforce Oppurtunity Object. The documents are sent and are getting signed and goes to completed  state in DocuSign but it is not getting attached back to Salesforce after the signing is done/Docusign status is completed.

Below is the settings for Salesforce connect object
[image]
[image]

I dont see anything getting attached

[image]

The Document shows completed status in DocuSign

[image]

Am I missing something why it doesnt attach the signed document to Salesforce Object

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely want to open a case with [DocuSign Support](https://support.docusign.com/) for troubleshooting. If you do, be sure to include an Envelope ID of a test send.

Things to check:

- Is the DocuSign Status record being updated in Salesforce? If not, you'll first want to check the link from DS back to SF. Log in to `DocuSign > Go to Admin > Connect > Reconfigure Login`
- are you sending from the same Opportunity the attachment should be writing back to?
- Do you have `Use Content Files` checked in your DocuSign Connect configuration page? If so, check the `Reconfigure Login` panel and confirm that `Salesforce SOAP Web Services API Version` is `39`

Comment: Thanks for the help. How can I check the DocuSign Status in SF, see the new attachment I dont see any Envelop# Status for the documents I sent today. 2. Yes I am trying to attach the signed document back to the same Oppurtunity from where I am sending it to sign. 3. I set this changed the version to 39 still no change.   We still dont have license with Docusign and using the trial version and I am not sure I can create a support ticket. I asked in their forums though but no response yet.

Comment: In Salesforce, go to the DocuSign Status tab, change `View: All`, and look for the Envelope ID of a recent send. If no status record is there at all, it's most likely bad credentials, but it could be a matter of permissions, or other restrictions unique to your SF environment.